# On local works, on server shows 404

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need help with something I don't understand.

I am developing a website for a customer.
I am doing on local, and every day upload to the server all changes and new things.

Last I done is create a simple way to extract the section, parameters and values from url. Is something like:

```
http://mywebsite.com/product/color/red
```

Really is not a shop, but this example shows clearly I want to tell you.

The idea is that I have a folder with the sections (product.php, home.php, contact.php, ...) and the section on url says the file to use.

This is working on my computer.

But now I've uploaded all files (literally) to server and not is working.
Shows me a 404 error.

I think the problem is into .htaccess and the PHP versions (I works on php 5.5.10 on local, and server runs on 5.4.16).

This is .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?params=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't know if you need something more information about all this. If you want, say it and I show you.

I hope you can help me.

Thank you!

**UPDATE 2015 July 02**

I tried a lot of thing and none worked.

Finally I tried to redirect to google, but not works. And I tried even break it with some wrong code into .htacces, but neither.

Searching I've read that the problem is *AllowOverride* is none.

For this I tried:

```
<Directory "/var/www/sites-public/laceart.cadt.com/html/">
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^test\.html http://www.google.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Still not working. But I don't know if Document Root is correct.

Can someone to help me?

Comment: Probably need to add `RewriteBase /` to before the conditions else apache will look for the file `index.php` in the current directory you are trying to load which would be something like `/product/color/index.php` and that doesn't exist. `RewriteBase` will overwrite the path so rewrites route to the specified directory. If that doesn't help, look at the appache error log (default: `/var/log/apache2/error.log`) and it should show you the page that is being requested that is missing.

Comment: I think is not correct because on local is working.

Even so I've trusted in you and try to use it, but not working.
:/

Comment: The configuration on local might be different from server (which is why this would be happening). Try looking at the error log next and see what page it is requesting. You could also change `index.php` to `/index.php` which might help.

Comment: Is solved.
My costumer told me that mod_rewrite was not enabled for the folder that I working.